# falls down on the ground from the roof

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1) He falls down on the ground from the roof of the house.
>
> 2) He falls to the ground from the roof of the house.

I think both sentences are grammatically correct. But something else is wrong with this sentence, I'm not sure what it is. "on the ground from the roof" looks strange to me. Is there better way to construct this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got your finger on what's wrong with S1:

> "on the ground from the roof".

That makes no sense. One falls **from the roof *to* the ground** or **from the roof *onto* the ground**. One cannot fall **from the roof *on* the ground** unless the roof is at ground level. This is a lexical & semantic problem.

So you can say, in addition to your S2,

> "He falls from the roof of the house (on)to the ground".

I'd use "**to the ground**".

Answer (score 2):

In your case, *fall* means "to drop down from a higher level to a lower level."

> Several of the books had fallen onto the floor.

> He fell 20 meters onto the rocks below.

> He falls onto the ground from the house roof.

You could also say "He falls from the house roof." but it would not be explicit that he fell/falls onto the ground; maybe that would be understood from the person who is listening.

Comment: kiam, can we say "his career fell within two days"? In other words, can we use "fall" even if there are no bodies or concrete things involved in the process of falling?